# GRUB2 stopped detecting Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

For a few restarts GRUB detected Windows but it suddenly stopped detecting Windows. I have no idea how this thing works, but basically I have Windows 10 on `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda1` should be Windows System Reserve partition (500 Mb).
I tried `sudo update-grub` This basically adds Ubuntu and its options.  I completely reinstalled GRUB and yet not effect. Can someone please tell me how do I add Windows 10 to boot options which is on `/dev/sda2` I don't think I have hibernated Windows because I am able to access the Windows file system from Ubuntu. I have tried quite a lot of tricks for this and none of them worked, which is why I posted the question (don't mark it duplicate).
Here is the [BootInfo Summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JfXfmK5DMy/)

 Thanks

Comment: Boot-Repair says it cannot access your sda2. Error opening '/dev/sda2': Resource temporarily unavailable. You may need to temporarily install Windows boot loader to MBR, move boot flag back to sda1, fix Windows issues which may be chkdsk, fast start up, hibernation or other issues. Then restore grub & run `sudo update-grub` Separately you had installed Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode to MBR drive. And Windows is in the now 35 year old BIOS boot mode which requires MBR partitioning. But you must have the newer UEFI hardware. BIOS Windows has to have boot flag on primary NTFS partition with boot files.

Comment: @oldfred how do I install windows boot loader to MBR? I only have access to Ubuntu... Can you give me a link from which I can see how to do this

Comment: You should have a repair disk or live installer for every system you have installed. And Linux cannot do most Windows fixes. But a generic Windows type boot loader is used by lilo & syslinux and either will work. You only want the part of the boot loader that goes in the MBR, not the full boot loader. And boot flag must be on Windows partition with boot files. https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on/422023#422023  You may be able to get Boot-Repair advanced mode to install syslinux boot loader.

Comment: I tried using syslinux... I tried the command `sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda1` I also tried it for /dev/sda but it is not working out... Can you give me like a step by step guide... I'm sorry for the trouble

Comment: Now I'm getting a message at the start saying `Checking media presence... No media found` after which the GRUB screen shows up. I have no idea what to do @oldfred

Comment: Here is another BootInfo[http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MCFTfr3pqR/]

Comment: New pastebin does not show. But you almost never install grub to a partition like sda1 and never ever to a NTFS partition which you just did. That damages Windows boot as it has vital boot info in the partition boot sector (BS or PBR). Luckily it keeps a backup BS which you may be able to restore with test disk It may say grub is valid as it can be, but never with NTFS. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#NTFS_Boot_sector_recovery & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix  If backup BS is valid restore it.